# Colocar boton disibled o enabled según condicion de valor

Tags: php, javascript, botón, function

Mi caso es el siguiente:
En una rutina coloco el mis botones en Disabled con el fin de ser evaluados en una rutina en PHP, de cumplir con un estado, estos botones deben convertir su atributo en disabled o contrario. el problema es que solo el primer registro es evaluado y el resto queda disabled.
Estoy seguro que es un error de principiante, pero me tiene estancado mi proyecto. a continuacion el codigo:

```
***<td class="text-right">
    <button type="button" title='Editar Transacción' id="boton_01" disabled>  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
    <button type="button" title='Descargar transaccion' id="boton_02" onclick="imprimir_transaccion('<?php echo $id_transaccion;?>');" disabled>  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i></button>
    <button type="button" title='Borrar transaccion' id="boton_03" onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id_transaccion; ?>')" disabled>  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
    <?php
        cambia_attr($stt_actual,$id_transaccion);
    ?
</td>***
```

Luego en mi archivo valida.php tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
***<?php
    function cambia_attr($atributo, $id_tansaccion) {
        if ($atributo == "0") {
            Activar($id_tansaccion);
        } else {
            Desactivar($id_tansaccion);
        }
    }
    function Activar($id){
        echo($id);
        ?>
        <script>
            $("#boton_01").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#boton_02").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#boton_03").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        </script> 
        <?php
    }
    function Desactivar($id){
        echo($id);
        ?>
        <script>
            $("#boton_01").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#boton_02").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#boton_03").removeAttr("disabled");
        </script> 
        <?php
    }
?>***
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que hagas la condición directamente en un único bloque javascript no es buena practica alterar el DOM para cargar javascript de esa manera.

```
<script>
    let activar = (estado) => {
      if (estado === true) {
        $("#boton_03").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      } else {
        $("#boton_01").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Godie007. Mucha gracias por la sugerencia. La tomare en cuenta. Sin embargo al aplicar el cambio, persiste el problema. solo el primer registro es el que cambia el estado de los botones. el resto queda apagado